# Extract decimal part into variable in XSL template

Tags: xslt, format, decimal

I need to store the 2 places after decimal (currency amount, so need only upto 2 places) in an XSL variable before I do a ceil function.

```
<xsl:element name="BaseFare"><xsl:value-of select="ceiling(BaseAmount/Amount * (1 - ($promoDisc div 100)))"/></xsl:element>
```

For eg. if the result of the Amount is 499 and promoDisc = 8%, then the discounted Amount would be 459.08 - I need to store "08" (with the zero) in a variable for use later, while I return the ceiling amount (460) in the output XML. Thought I could just do a string function and read 2 chars after the decimal into a variable rather than do any math?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are different ways to do this extraction:

**I. Using the string representation of the number**:

```
concat('.',substring(substring-after($x, '.'), 1, 2))
```

**II. Using standard math functions**:

```
$x - floor($x)
```

This evaluates to the decimal part of any positive number `$x`.

Use one of the functions: **[`format-number()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#function-format-number)**, **[`round()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-round)**, **[`round-half-to-even()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-round-half-to-even)** (the last function available only XPath 2.0 / XSLT 2.0) to round it to two decimal places.

In XSLT 1.0 one way to get from a positive number exactly the digits in the two decimal places after the decimal point (truncate without rounding),  is:

```
format-number(
              floor(100* $x) div 100
             -
              floor(floor(100* $x) div 100),
              '.00'
              )
```

**Here is a complete example of the described methods:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">

   <xsl:value-of select=
   "concat('.',substring(substring-after(0.12543, '.'), 1, 2))"/>
=========
   <xsl:value-of select=
      "format-number(0.12543, '.00')"/>
=========
   <xsl:value-of select=
    "format-number(
                   floor(100* 999.12543) div 100
                  -
                   floor(floor(100* 999.12543) div 100),
                   '.00'
                   )
      "/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on any XML document (not used), the result is:**

```
   .12
=========
   .13
=========
   .12
```

Comment: Excellent! Thanks - worked like a charm - and as always taught me some tricks too.

Comment: That was quite useful as Qt does not currently offer `format-number()`.